Sent USDT(sol) to PYUSD (sol) contract address
I have accidentally sent my usdt in sol network to PYUSD contact address 2b1kV6DkPAnxd5ixfnxCpjxmKwqjjaYmCZfHsFu24GXo in sol network. Could i back my money? Paxos company is responsible for this Paypal token in solana network.

You probably ended up sending the USDT to a nested ATA. If that's the case, you can use RecoverNested:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/57136f27d4dec1b1910220e7bf6d53457212b701/associated-token-account/program/src/instruction.rs#L49
Unfortunately you'll have to write a script, I'm not aware of a front end tool to call that ix.
You can read more here: https://www.sec3.dev/blog/two-caveats-spl

I, too, just made this mistake.
Their support doesn't even know how their platform works, let alone cryptocurrency.
I've been talking to them via voice and chat for 25 hours, and the "best" solution yet is to "log in to PayPal.com and transfer or sell."
They honestly don't understand that it would take someone a minute to convert the USDT to PYUSD or just send the USDT back.
For goodness' sake, they should have a smart contract that returns anything other than PYUSD or converts whatever Solana coin sent to PYUSD.
They are a payment solution company that decided to create its coin on two different highly programmable blockchains.
I could fix their issue in a day and stop this from happening.
But then PayPal wouldn't be able to steal your money.
Just think about how many people have made this mistake? I guarantee you it's millions of dollars worth of USDT a year in free profits.
I'll keep on them and let you know what happens when I finally get someone who doesn't have to read a script and has a little motivation to act.

I'm Newbie on crypto but everybody tell ne that if i sent a token to a wrong address the token cant reach the destination and get lost on the blockchain.  Sometimes exchanges can search the tokens but they charge a fee for that service so you have to evaluate if this fee is less than the amount you sent. Ask to your exchange maybe they can recall and get your money Back. That happened to me 2 monthhs ago but the fee was much more than the amount that i sent so i gave my tokens as lost. Hope your exchange could get your tokens back to you. Best regards
